# how to create a page push in angularjs using the ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following structure
The idea is that when you click this item, I am taken to a page post.html

**Controller:**

```
$scope.showPost = function (index) {

    $rootScope.postContent = $scope.items[index];
    $scope.navi.pushPage('post.html'); //this does not work, I want to create something to take me to that page
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item ng-click="showPost($index)">HERE</ion-item>
```

Comment: There's not enough information in this question for anyone to provide you an answer. Please add more details so the community can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a route (See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/)

Then inject $state in your controller declaration and do :

```
$state.go('post.html')
```

PS : populating the rootScope is generally a bad practice.